# (error) ERR unknown command 'redis-cli'

Tags: node.js, cmd, redis, connection, redis-cli

We have installed the [redis client](https://github.com/rgl/redis/downloads).

When we type the following command inside `C:\Program Files\Redis\redis-cli.exe`:

```
redis-cli -h redis-server.example.com -p 6390 ping
```

It throws the following error:

> (error) ERR unknown command 'redis-cli'

And the same command when fired inside inside `C:\Windows\System32\cmd.exe` throws the following error:

> 'redis-cli' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Notice that [`Path` is set to `C:\Program Files\Redis\redis-cli.exe`](https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-39-redis-cli-39-is-not-recognized-22667)

What is the problem?

Comment: Only put the directory containing redis-cli.exe into the `PATH`. `C:\Program Files\Redis`

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your PATH should be set to directory, not to the file

```
"C:\Program Files\Redis\"
```

Answer (score 3):

For me the `path` was the following:

```
C:\Program Files\Memurai
```

Then I had to run the following command instead:

```
memurai-cli
```

The [`Memurai`](https://www.memurai.com/blog/memurai-a-redis-alternative-for-windows) is a Redis Alternative for Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it helps anyone, but you can also go into your program files find `redis-cli`, right click, go to `properties`, `Location`:

```
C:\ProgramFiles\Redis
```

This can be ran in to your shell.